# property 'tableView' not found on object of type -

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to add a row to a tableView using the following code. I am trying to download the RSS feeds and as the feeds are downloaded, they are dynamically added to the tableView - row by row.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

    RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:request.url.absoluteString
                                              articleTitle:request.url.absoluteString
                                                articleUrl:request.url.absoluteString
                                               articleDate:[NSDate date]] autorelease];    
    int insertIdx = 0;                    
    [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]                        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}
```

It gives me the error - **property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'ChecklistsViewController *' [3]**

I have a single view application and the root view controller is called ChecklistsViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your ChecklistsViewController have a property called tableView of type UITableView?

Did you maybe intend to use a UITableViewController as the superclass for ChecklistsViewController, but actually used a UIViewController instead?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe declaring your class as a subclass of UIViewController not a UITableViewController.